# Geting Runtime Error "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Tags: vb.net, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

here i m creating the outlook add in. where i create a one menu bar Item and add one button on menu bar.when i run the application i get a run time error "Value does not fall within the expected range" in the MyMenuBar() method on initializing the _objNewMenuBar. can any one suggest me why its giving me such type or error.this is a stacktrace value wherei m getting error
 **at Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarControls.Add(Object Type, Object Id, Object Parameter, Object Before, Object Temporary)
   at TROutlookAddOn.ThisAddIn.MyMenuBar()**

```
Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
    Me.MyMenuBar()
End Sub

Private Sub MyMenuBar()
    Me.ErsMyMenuBar()
    Try
        'Define the existent Menu Bar
        _objMenuBar = Me.Application.ActiveExplorer.CommandBars.ActiveMenuBar
        'Define the new Menu Bar into the old menu bar
        _objNewMenuBar = CType(_objMenuBar.Controls.Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, missing, missing, missing, False), Office.CommandBarPopup)
        If (Not (_objNewMenuBar) Is Nothing) Then
            _objNewMenuBar.Caption = "Talent Recruit"
            _objNewMenuBar.Tag = menuTag
            _objButton = CType(_objNewMenuBar.Controls.Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, missing, missing, 1, True), Office.CommandBarButton)
            _objButton.Caption = "Import Resume"
            Dim newIcon As System.Drawing.Icon = My.Resources.recruit_logo
            Dim newImageList As ImageList = New ImageList
            newImageList.Images.Add(newIcon)
            _objButton.Picture = ConvertImage.Convert(newImageList.Images(0))
            _objButton.Style = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonIconAndCaption
            'Icon 
            '_objButton.FaceId = 500;
            _objButton.Tag = "ItemTag"
            'EventHandler
            AddHandler _objButton.Click, AddressOf Me._objButton_Click
            _objNewMenuBar.Visible = True
        End If
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(("Error: " + ex.Message.ToString), "Error Message")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for remove all missing variable from method